# Emboss effect for a LinearLayout in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, background-color, emboss

I have a textview and imageview inside horizontal linearlayout which has blue color as its background. How can i add Emboss effect for the lineatlayout? Please help me

Comment: what do u mean Emboss effect ?can u explian clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does provide some feature for creating an Emboss Effect by using EmbossMaskFilter..

For more details, you can visit this link: http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2012/05/example-of-embossmaskfilter.html

Also if you need to apply this effect for 2D-graphics, then you can use this link: http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/07/2d-graphics-with-effects_11.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a 9 patch with the emboss built into the image.

That way you can make the size and colour whatever you want.